# Nodejs: many clients requests through one socket

Tags: sockets, networking, proxy, node.js

Scenario: I have many clients (web pages, via Socket.io) that connect to a Node.js server (call it A). The server acts as an application "proxy" to another service (Node.js too) for those clients, let's call the service B. In practice, pages talk to service B using the proxy. 
I'm trying to understand if I could take ONE only open socket from the server A to the service B, just to gain performance and resources (on the first client connection on server A, the server will open the socket to B and maintain it open for message to flow bidirectionally).
Of course the problem is that without some kind of intervention, messages could be scrambled one over the other, resulting in a mess that service B can't understand.
I'm quite a newbie in socket programming, and I'm wondering if this is yet a "solved" problem, or just the wrong answer to the problem :)
Thank you

Comment: I'd separate messages with a \n and then on B looping on a .split("\n")...

Comment: It really depends on how you're proxying requests from A to B. Could you post some example code?

Comment: Ehi Rob, it's really simple: A and B talk via a TCP socket, so they share a data stream in which the messages from the client and the relevant answers from B flow. The problem is that messages in the stream have to be "enveloped", packet-ized. I'm now using a simple "\n" delimited "protocol" then... it seems to work

Comment: Ah, ok. I understand now but I'm curious why you "rolled your own" protocol over TCP rather than using a higher level protocol (like HTTP REST)? Using a raw TCP connection, if the message you're sending has to be fragmented into more than one packet (a process you have no control over), your server will receive more than one 'data' event and will have to reconstruct the message.

Comment: Yeah, I indeed fear the fragments. The problem with HTTP is that the service (B) would also (on its own initiative) send messages to the clients. Something imperative and asyncronous (broadcasting too, if necessary). Think of the service as a "brain" that chews data and take decisions based on the data. Quite complicated :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments, it looks like you'd benefit from something like Redis' PubSub.

See http://redis.io/ and specifically, http://redis.io/commands#pubsub

Comment: I accept the answer because I already used Redis pub/sub for another project of mine and I'll maybe use it as well in this one. (already thinking about it). Thank you :)